# Why is Brahma depicted as old in pictures?

Tags: gods, brahma

[image: Brahma]
[image: The Trimurti]

I have seen many pictures and photos (such as above) of Chaturmukha Brahma  with **white hair and white beard**. Why is Brahma shown as an old person? All the devatas are known to be drinking elixir (amruth). It is said that those who drink it do not feel hunger, thirst and do not age, so, *look always young*. My question is Brahma being one of the Trimurti's, didn't He get a chance to drink elixir? Or did anyone curse Him to look like that? Is Brahma not an immortal? I know that being a Brahma is only a status.
 What happens to this Brahma after his tenure is over?

Comment: Gods of course don't grow old but what if He is like that from the beginning?

Comment: @Rickross Will you please explain me how to insert images into the questions?I could not understand it from the website help.

Comment: @SreeCharan I have updated your question. Images will be displayed soon.

Comment: Related: [Why is Lord Brahma mostly depicted as an old man in most Indian depictions while Shiva and Vishnu are not?](https://www.quora.com/Epics-of-India-Why-is-Lord-Brahma-mostly-depicted-as-an-old-man-in-most-Indian-depictions-while-Shiva-and-Vishnu-are-not)

Comment: I agree with @Rickross, I think he was born that way.  But I'm not sure whether Hindu scripture describes him as looking old or not.

Comment: May be because age of Brahma is 51 Years and we are not sure about Vishnu and Shiva (Rudra).

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah may be Age is the reason he is depicted like this. Since each mahakalpa is a year for Bramha

Comment: It is just an artist's impression which stuck over the ages. If you look at sculptures on temples etc., you see a youthful brahma deva. The original artist must have depicted him as an old man because he is the progenitor of all creatures and hence venerable.

Comment: @moonstar2001 What is relationship between Lady Gaga or Lord Bramha or any hindu god? I agree on the point of Artistic Interpolation but this Lady Gaga thing is rude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any scriptural references of the trinity "Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh(Shiva)" as depicted in popular culture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/are-there-any-scriptural-references-of-the-trinity-brahma-vishnu-maheshshiva)

Comment: @iammilind If you are going to close, close your question and think they are duplicates. this was asked before that question.

Comment: You may want to learn to be broad minded about content driven websites. While closing as dupes, we don't have to see the dates. We have to see the relevance. The Qn which you refer as "Mine" is a superset of the Qn which you refer as "yours". Hence I have voted for closure. See [this Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23844/1049) OR [this Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8668/1049) OR [this Qn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48710758/514235), which is among long list of Qn-s, which I have self closed. I may not discuss any further, unless I find your counter arguments sensible.

Comment: @iammilind Don't close an old question based on answers which got later. We follow closure based on questions itself here. SO model is not followed. I'm well aware that the content is important than the date asked. Neither you nor me will gain nothing if we close this question. The content of both the questions are not same or relevant. My question asks why are they depicted like that and the other question is asking for references about the depiction. Hence not dupe. Even I have self closed.  By _your_, I meant the target linked by you not the question asked by you. I mean no offense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brahma is often referred to as ["pitamaha"](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=pitAmaha&direction=SE&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=0) (forefather or grandfather) in scriptures, so I think some of the pictures that portray him in human form with white hair and beard is to just show how he is older than some of the other gods.

From Valmiki Ramayana, here are a few verses that refer to Brahma as pitamaha:

> - इति एवम् उक्त्वा देवेशः सर्वलोक **पितामहः** | 
>     यथा आगतम् तथा अगच्छत् देव लोकम् महायशाः || १-४४-१६
>
>   16. sarva loka pitaa mahaH = for all, worlds, forefather; mahaayashaaH deva iishaH = great glorious, gods, lord of - Brahma; iti evam uktvaa = thus, this way, on saying; yathaa aagatam tathaa = as came in, like that; deva lokam agacChat = to empyrean, world, went away.
>
>   On saying in this way, **the forefather of all the worlds**, and the great glorious lord of all gods, **namely Brahma**, went away to his empyrean world as he has came. [[Bala Kanda, Sarga 44, Verse 16](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga44/balasans44.htm#Verse16)]
> - ततह् स्वायम्भुवैर्मन्रैर्ब्रह्मस्त्रमभिमन्त्रितम् | 
>     हनुमांश्चिन्तयामास वरदानम् **पितामहात्** || ५-४८-४०
>
>   40. brahmaastram = (knowing it) to be missile presided over by Brahma the creator; abhimantram = and consecrated; mantraiH = by spells; svaayambhuvaiH = sacred to Brahma the creator; hanuman = Hanuma; tataH = then; chintayaamaasa = recollected; varadaanam = a boon got; pitaamahaat = by Lord Brahama; the grand-father of the entire creation.
>
>   Knowing it to be a missile presided over by Brahma the creator and consecrated by spells sacred to Brahma, the creator, Hanuma then recollected a boon got by **Lord Brahma, the grand father of the entire creation.** [[Sundara Kanda, Sarga 48, Verse 40](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga48/sundarasans48.htm#Verse40)]

This is no different from how Bhishma is depicted in [paintings](http://krishnaimages.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/4_KrishnaAttacksBhishma.jpg).

Comment: If Bramha is grandfather then Shri hari Vishnu should be great grand father of everything older than bramha he is, since Bramha is born out of Naabhi Kamala(Lotus Navel) of  Shri hari Vishnu.

Answer (score 7):

We live in Second half of Brahma i.e, we live in 51st Year of Brahma.

[Srimad Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/11/34) says

> yad ardham āyuṣas tasya 
>   parārdham abhidhīyate 
>  pūrvaḥ
> parārdho ’pakrānto 
>   hy aparo ’dya pravartate
>
> The one hundred years of Brahmā’s life are divided into two parts, the
> first half and the second half. The first half of the duration of
> Brahmā’s life is already over, and the second half is now current.
>
> The duration of one hundred years in the life of Brahmā has already
> been discussed in many places , and it is described in
> [Bhagavad-gītā (8.17)](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/8/17) also. Fifty years of the life of Brahmā are
> already over, and fifty years are yet to be completed; then, for
> Brahmā also, death is inevitable.

[Skanda Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27477/62f_chapter_19_1.pdf) also states we live in second [Paraardha](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?beginning=0%20&tinput=%20Paraardha%20&trans=Translate) of Brahma.

> 54-56.  In the second Parardha of Brahma, the thirteenth Kalpa was
> well-known as Pitri Kalpa.

Pitri Kalpa was Kalpa before Sweta Varaha Kalpa and according to Skanda Purana we live in 14th day of Brahma (as 14th Kalpa is Swetha Varaha Kalpa). But some Puranas contradict this.

As age of the Brahma is 51, Artists might be depicting Him as man with white beard and white hair. But Vishnu and Rudra are depicted as Young due to differences in their life spans.

[Shiva Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9290/3500) says

> A day of Brahma's life constitutes life of 14 Indras. A day of Vishnu
> is lifetime of Brahma. A day of Rudra is life time of Vishnu. A day of Shiva is life time of Rudra. A day of SadaaShiva is life period of Shiva. A day of SAAKSHAATSHIVA is life period of SadaaShiva.

Due to this difference in lifespan, Vishnu and Rudra might be depicted as young when compared to Brahma.

[Brahma gets Moksha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9100/3500) after He completes 100 years.

.

Answer (score 5):

When you consider Brahma, he is:

- The teacher.
- The creator, who created everything.
- The knowledge.

He is more portrayed as **a teacher**, **a sage** with all knowledge of universe. So He is portrayed as an old man.

Also, by the Vedas, they say:

> *Brahma is the physical reflection of the ancient Upanishadic universal Brahman. One can therefore see age and wisdom in such a depiction.*

Source: [Why is Lord Brahma mostly depicted as an old man in most Indian depictions while Shiva and Vishnu are not?](https://www.quora.com/Epics-of-India-Why-is-Lord-Brahma-mostly-depicted-as-an-old-man-in-most-Indian-depictions-while-Shiva-and-Vishnu-are-not)

Comment: @sv. Thanks buddy, this is my first post on Hinduism. BTW, I quoted the article from where it says, and it is not Wikipedia. `:)` I will definitely verify it and update the post if needed. Thanks.

Comment: @sv. Definitely.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have added the source as well, is that not enough? What is the expectation from the source? 

Answer (score -1):

Brahma has white hairs because of two reasons:

1. he is the creator (to create something we need knowledge)
2. he writes everyone's faith (from humans faith to animals faith)

So therefore due to a lot of knowledge and stress in his brain he got white hairs and white beard.