# Physical appearance of various Gods for worship

Tags: gods, belief, culture

This is question about pictorial representation of various gods, especially their facial hair.

Brahma has a full beard & moustache. But Vishnu (including RAma, Krishna incarnations) and Shankara are picturized clean shaven. Was there any puranic reference to their appearance or may be classical painters like Ravi Varma imagined in a certain way and it caught on?
 In case of Ganesha or Hanuman, who are also without facial hair,  the ancient descriptions are so vivid that deity's swaroopa visualization has never been a problem to us.

Comment: Well frankly speaking you don't need God's appearance or form to worship.:) As Sri Krishn said that he has no form but he takes incarnation when ever necessary.

Comment: I also got this doubt and asked this question - Related  [Why is Brahma depicted as old in pictures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11259/why-is-brahma-depicted-as-old-in-pictures). Actually, Brahma is not an old and doesn't have white beard and moustache. It is only artistic license. He is normal and young like any other deities.

Comment: Beard, moustache and clean shave is mostly artistic licence. Skanda Purana says Shiva had beard after Sati's death..

Comment: This is just hearsay from elders - Brahma is affectionately known as pitamaha (or grandfather) - since he created everyone, he is the oldest of us all, so he is depicted with a beard. Vishnu is nitya-yuva (always young), even though he created Brahma, so he is depicted clean-shaven. Shiva is already depicted with Jata (mattlocks of hair), so why add beard also ? We can imagine Gods as we want, it is upto individual devotion (Bhakti)

Comment: Liked this one about man made gods,, well, almost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appearance of various deities is divined by RSi's and described in dhyAna zlOkAs of various mantrAs/stOtrAs and vedic verses.

For e.g., viSNu is described as "zAntAkAram bhujaga zayanam, padmanAbham gagana sadRzam" and "mEgha zyAmam, pIta kauzEya vAsam, zrIvatsAnkam, punDarIkAkSam" etc., You will find these descriptions in the beginning of viSNu sahasranAma stOtram.

Similarly, ziva in his dakSiNAmurti form is described as " mauna vyAkhyA prakaTita parabramha tatvam, yuvAnam, karakalita cinmudram, mudita vadanam " etc.

Also the vedic mantra "trayambakam yajAmahe" describes the appearance of Lord Shiva.

There are many purANAs also that describe the appearance of the divine. For e.g., the form of nArAyaNa that appeared to dhRva is described in detail in the bhagavata purana.

The hymn to mahAlakSmi composed by Indra, viz, "namastEstu mahAmAye" describes the goddess in detail.

In general, rishis' and devatas' compositions expound and extol the rupa ( form), guna (attributes) and lIla (divine sport) of the deities and are a result of their visualisation which in turn in the result of their penance.

Comment: why zlOKAs instead of shlOKAs?

Comment: Yes, why halfway? why not mahAlakzmI instead of mahalakSmi when Siva is ziva? Likewise rupa rather than rUpa, guNa rather than guna, and bhAgavata purANa rather than bhagavata purana? And what should be used when a noun is plural? It is purANA: or a plural of purANa, but purANAs is confusing as we are using half od the sanskrit plural with the english plural. And we have only one 'o' in Sanskrit.

Comment: That said, it is definitely a good attempt.

Comment: @ram HK scheme transliterates to z (as in zankara), s (as in samskritam) and S (as in Sanmukha) all three different.

Comment: @user1952500  You are right - I  need to be thorough. Regarding plurals etc., it is better not to use perfect sanskrit grammar as it will likely be lost on most readers. And it is mahAlakSmi not lakzmi

Comment: @moonstar2001 this is a nice attempt. Here most people only care about a vs A so seeing someone do it for 'I' etc is very nice. +1

Comment: @user1952500 Would you like to pop into the Sanskrit chat room? One of the users has a lot of questions and I am out of my depth . Thanks.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63735/sanskrit

Comment: I'll try. My knowledge is limited to basics.

Comment: uneven capitalization is making it hard to read this answer.

Comment: @user13107 that's the result of transliterating sanskrit words into english. sorry. It has the same effect as english diacritics / phonetic symbols.

Comment: @moonstar2001 you can also add devnagri script right? why this confusing script which very few people know?

Comment: @user13107 Even fewer know devanagari. This is the best compromise. Besides, its easier than having to install fonts etc. So for all these reasons, I will continue to transliterate as best as I can.

Comment: @user1952500 Yes, people here are only concerned about the A and not other letters. This is a blunder by many.  Even if we edit with proper transliteration, they roll back saying it is a proper noun so, it should be capital. Now, how did English grammar and ITRANS mix? XD I use IAST transliteration in my questions and answers. IAST looks good to me.

Comment: @Sinister The mix above was like this: you have purANa: as singular and purANA: as plural in Sanskrit. Now, some people translate the plural as purANAs. Note that they follow the plural spelling(last A) and add the 's'. I would expect an English plural to be the singular followed by 's': purANas. It is a strange thing to excise the : in the Sanskrit plural and add the 's'.

Comment: @user1952500 1.Transliteration is to aid with pronunciation of foreign words (Sanskrit is foreign to English)2.There is no English  equivalent of the word purAna. In Eng, purana is still purana. We are primarily writing in Eng  here; not sanskrit. So we follow rules of english grammar (to the best of our ability) 3. Inter-mixing grammars of the two languages will throw the sentence structure for a loop. French words appropriated into english follow english rules of grammar. E.g.,the plural of cafe is cafes, that of chauffeur is chauffeurs . Similarly the plural of purana in English is puranas.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I was just referring to the fact that some people write the singular as 'purANa' and the plural as 'purANAs'. Notice the  capitalization of the last 'A' in the plural. That is a mix of sanskrit and english. We could have purANas and that would be fine. The word 'purANAs' is a strange mix.

Comment: @user1952500 How do we say it in sanskrit? With the elongated, "aa" or the shortened one?

Comment: @moonstar2001 we do elongate but we put in the ':'. For example, the word mother is 'jananI' and the plural is 'jananya:'. So would the transliteration be 'jananyas' or 'jananIs'?

Comment: @user1952500 :-D jananIs ?

Comment: @moonstar2001 similarly I think the plural transliteration should be purANas rather than purANAs. It's a philosophical discussion with not much value in any case :)

Comment: @user1952500  I still feel pronunciation trumps in matters of transliteration. purANas sound weird to me.

Comment: Agreed about the pronunciation. Definitely purANas sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Gopala-Purva-Taaapani Sruti(1/2) says, Sri Krishna is ever-young

> Gopavesham avraabham TARUNAM kalpadrumasritam.

Brihat-Bhagavataamritam(2/5/122) says

> vayas cha tachchaishavashovayashritam sadaa tathaa jauvanaleelayadritam/ manojna-kaishora-dasha-avalamvitam pratikshanam nutanam nutanam gunair.

In the commentary of the above sloka, Srila Sanatana Goswami writes:

> Sri Krishna is ever-young(chira-kishora), ever-beautiful and always without mustache and beard.

In Srimad-Bhagavatam(3/28/17), Sri Kapila says to His mother Devi Devahuti that 'Graceful God is always ever-young'. (Reference: Mahaprabhu Sri Gauranga, Radhagovinda Nath, Sadhana Prakashani, page 146-147).

So Vishnu and His incarnations are always depicted without beard and mustache (probably the only exception is the image at Sri Parthasarathy temple Chennai.)

Other forms of Gods and Goddesses are also mostly depicted as young as that is mentioned in their dhyanamantras. For example, the dhyana-mantra of Devi Durga in Kalika-Purana and Brihat Nandikeswara-Purana and quoted in the Puja-Paddhati book mention Her as 'Nava-yauvana-sampanna'. The complexion, number of arms, the astras etc are almost always explicitly mentioned in the dhyana-mantras.

Devi Dhumavati of the Dasa-Mahavidyas is depiceted as aged as per Her dhyana-mantra. (Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das,Vol 1, chapter 11. The appendix gives dhyanamantras of Devis).

Brahma is shown with beard in many images probably because He is generally referred to as Grand-father (Pitamaha).

Regarding Hanumanji, I did see different types of images, with and without beard and the mantras composed by Tulsidasji do not mention it clearly so far as I know.