# How does Brahma look?

Tags: scripture, puranas, gods, brahma

Does Brahma look like an old deity, having white hair? What is his body complexion - red, golden or something else. Does he use rosaries for chanting? If so then which rosaries does he use(rudraksha or tulasi mala)? Which type of tilak does he put on his forehead - urdhava pundra (u shaped tilak of Vishnu) or tripundra (three lined tilak of Shiva)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Brahma depicted as old in pictures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11259/why-is-brahma-depicted-as-old-in-pictures)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto this answer describes about why he was depicted as an old deity, but doesn't clears my other doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know how a deity looks like we need to look into that deity's Dhyana Shloka (also called Dhyana Mantra sometimes).

For Lord BrahmA, since his worship is prohibited, it's difficult to find a Dhyana Mantra. But I know about a DhyAna Shloka, that is quoted in the book **Anhika Kritya (by Shyamacharana Kaviratna Varidhi)**; first BhAga; first Khanda; section-DhyAnamAlA.

And, it is as follows:

> BrahmA kamandalu-dharashchaturvaktrash-chaturbhujah |
> KadAchidrakta-kamale hamsArudhah kadAchana ||
>  Varnena
> rakta-gaurAngah prAmshustunganga unnatah |
>  Kamandalur-vAmakare
> sruvo haste tu dakshine ||
>  DakshinAdhastathA mAlA vAmAdhascha
> tathA sruchA |
>  AjyasthAli vAmapArshwe vedAh sarvehagratah stithAh
> ||
>  SAvitri vAma-pArshwasthA dakshinasthA saraswati |
>  Sarvve
> cha rishayo hyagre kuryadevishcha chintanam ||
>
> Lord BrahmA holds the Kamandalu (a water pot); he is having four faces
> and four arms;  Sometimes (he is seen) seated on a red lotus and
> sometimes on the Swan. His body is having an extremely stout structure
> and is having a reddish-white complexion. The upper left hand is
> holding the Kamandalu and the lower right hand holds the rosary beads;
> the lower left hand holds the Sruk (the laddle used while pouring the
> Havi in fire); the upper right hand is holding the Sruva (the utensil
> in which the Havi is stored);
>
> On his left hand side is present the AjyasthAli (the plate that
> contains clarified butter or Ghee); in his front (are present) the
> Vedas; on his left is present SAvitri and on his right Saraswati and
> in his front are present all the Rishis. One has to meditate upon Lord
> Brahma in this way.

So, it does not specify if Lord BrahmA is having white hair and white beard or not. Also, although it specifies that he carries a JapamAlA, but it does not specify what kind of beads (like RudrAksha, Tulasi or any other) that MAlA is made of. And, regarding the Tilaka on forehead, it has no information.

I have also consulted the Deva Kritha Brahma Stotram found [here](https://www.celextel.org/#gsc.tab=0) but it is not of any help regarding finding out details of Lord Brahma's physical appearance.

Similarly, I have also checked the [Brahma Stuthi Panchakam](https://www.celextel.org/#gsc.tab=0). But it too does not provide any additional information.

Comment: Nice answer, upvote. Doubt - are not Savitri and Saraswati the same Goddess different forms - somewhat like Durga and Kaushiki or Kali

Comment: Thanks @Archit Yes, sometimes they are different names of the same deity but sometimes they also differentiate between the two like it is done here.

Comment: Any particular reason? Similar in this case श्रीश्च ते लक्ष्मीश्च पत्न्यावहोरात्रे पार्श्वे। Shri and Lakshmi are your wives..... also aren’t Saraswati and Gayatri the same. When we see her as the all mother (just like Durgaji in some cases) and mother of Vedas she’s Gayatri, correct?

Comment: Sarswati and Gayatri are definitely different deities.@Archit

Comment: Different? Isn’t Saraswati also Vedamata like Gayatri? Wasn’t Saraswati the one who helped Brahma with the Vedas and creation?

Comment: Well they are different. They have different Dhyana Slokas, different mantras, worship procedures. When Dhyanam is different then we are talking about separate deities. @Archit

Comment: Okay thanks, will have to do more research

Comment: @Archit ok .. no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sri Shiva Maha Purana 2.1:1:7:1-6.:

> Brahmā said:—
>
> When lord Nārāyaṇa continued to sleep, an excellent lotus of huge size came out of his navel as desired by Śiva.
>
> It was many Yojanas wide and high. It had an endless stalk. The pericarp was of a brilliant hue.
>
> It was very beautiful with the brilliance of ten million suns. It was wonderful, excellent and worthy of vision containing Tattvas.
>
> Exerting himself as before, Śiva, the great lord, with Pārvatī as his better half created me from His right limb.
>
> O sage, having deluded me with His illusion immediately, Śiva in the course of His sport, produced me through the umbilical lotus of Viṣṇu.
>
> **Thus, it was that I came to be known as Lotus-born and conceived in a golden womb. I had four faces, red complexion and Tripuṇḍra-marked forehead.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..