# What is the source of rAmachandra having a green colored form?

Tags: rama

What is the source of Ramachandra having a green colored form? If I remember correctly, Shukavarna was the term used.

Comment: Related [Depiction of Rama and Krishna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7354/5212)

Answer (score 2):

Sri Sri Rama-RakshA-stotra by Budhakaushika rishi (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra  ) describes Sri RAma as

> rAmam durva-dala-shyAmam padmAksham pita-vAsasam/stuvanti nAmavir divyair na te samsArino narAh//(25), meaning **Rama is having dark complexion like durva-grass** and wearing yellow garment.Those who praise Him by different names are never bound by worldliness.(Reference: Stavananjali, Ramakrishna Math Nagpur,page 144)

The dhyana at the beginning of the stotra however describes Him as 'NiradAvam' meaning having complexion like cloud.(Ibid.page 142) and also as 'Nila-utpala-dala-shyAma' (complexion like blue lotus).

Tulsidasji also describes Him as 'Nilamvuja-shyAmala-komalangam' and so His skin colour is like blue lotus there: http://lordrama.co.in

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra