# Why is Rama depicted as having blue skin?

Tags: rama

Why is Rama depicted as having blue skin?
Why not brown like most Indians?

Comment: I am not sure using the word _depicted_ is correct here?

Comment: In the VIBGYOR, Violet-Blue is at highest frequency like the color of sky because of scattering, while Red, the color of earth-matter and blood is at the lowest frequency. https://www.livescience.com/33324-purple-royal-color.html

Comment: I think [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16767/277) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

While describing the characteristics of Sri Rama to Sita, Sri Hanuman says Sri Rama was of dark-complexioned.

> दुन्दुभि स्वन निर्घोषः स्निग्ध वर्णः प्रतापवान् |
>
> समः सम विभक्त अन्गो वर्णम् ***श्यामम्*** समाश्रितः || ५-३५-१६
>
> "He has a voice like the sound of a kettle-drum. He has a shining
>   skin. He is full of splendour. He is square-built. His limbs are built
>   symmetrically. He is endowed with a **dark complexion**."

The word used by Sage Valmiki was **श्यामम्**.

According to Sanskrit dictionary, [its meaning](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=zyAma&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) ranges from Green to Black to Blue.

So we can consider the complexion of Sri Rama to be dark-complexioned.