# What is the scriptural description of Shri Krshn's physical appearance?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, harivamsa

How did He look like during His infancy, childhood, boyhood, youth and adulthood?
Is there any mention of Him having an Ashtaratni body?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Depiction of Rama and Krishna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/depiction-of-rama-and-krishna)

Comment: @Archit - this QnA just answers their skin complexion and not physical manifestation.

Answer (score 1):

Lord Krishna's beauty is described wonderfully in Bhagavata Purana and is expounded further in Chaitanya Charitamrita.

> O son of the king of the cowherds, Your transcendental body is dark
> blue like a new cloud, Your garment is brilliant like lightning, and
> the beauty of Your face is enhanced by Your gunja earrings and the
> peacock feather on Your head. Wearing garlands of various forest
> flowers and leaves, and equipped with a herding stick, a buffalo horn
> and a flute, You stand beautifully with a morsel of food in Your
> hand.(SB 10.14.1)
>
> Krishna, is the reservoir of all beauty. All beautiful things emanate
> from Him, and His personal form is so attractive that it steals the
> eyes away from all other objects, which then seem devoid of beauty in
> comparison to Him. When Lord Krishna was on the earth, He attracted
> the eyes of all people. When he spoke, His words attracted the minds
> of all who remembered them. By seeing his footsteps, people became
> attracted to Him, and thus they wanted to offer their bodily
> activities to the Lord as His followers. In this way Krishna very
> easily spread His glories, which are sung throughout the world by the
> most sublime and essential Vedic verses. (SB 11.1.6–7)
>
> Ornaments caress that body, but the transcendental body of Krsna is so
> beautiful that it beautifies the ornaments He wears. Therefore Krsna's
> body is said to be the ornament of ornaments. Enhancing the wonderful
> beauty of Krsna is His three-curved style of standing. Above all these
> beautiful features, Krsna's eyes dance and move obliquely, acting like
> arrows to pierce the minds of Gopis. When the arrow succeeds in
> hitting its target, their minds become agitated.(CC Madhya 21.105)
>
> Dear Krsna, by seeing Your beautiful face decorated with tresses of
> hair, by seeing the beauty of Your earrings falling on Your cheeks,
> and by seeing the nectar of Your lips, the beauty of Your smiling
> glances, Your two arms, which assure complete fearlessness, and Your
> broad chest, whose beauty arouses conjugal attraction, we have simply
> surrendered ourselves to becoming Your maidservants.(CC Antya 15.70)